# Mysql new_auth_plugin: caching_sha2_password warning

Tags: python, mysql-connector

After installing MySQL and working for almost 1 month, I am facing below warning every time that I try to execute a query within a python script:

ANY HELP TO HANDLE THIS?

```
(MainThread) # _do_auth(): user: root
(MainThread) # _do_auth(): self._auth_plugin: 
(MainThread) new_auth_plugin: caching_sha2_password
(MainThread) # request: b'\xa5\x0c/\x14v\t\x86O\xa8\x84\xc7\x93\x8c8\x1c\xa9\x8b@\xaf\xa1' size: 20
(MainThread) # server response packet: bytearray(b'\x07\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: Is this causing an issue with your code or can your mysql connector handle the authentication?

Comment: my code works well, but these warnings is being printed every time, I want to haven't these warnings in my console.

Comment: I don't think these lines are warnings. This just seems to be a trace of what's happening.

Comment: Is there any way to disable these traces?

Comment: You ned to consult with the manual of whatever library you use to connect to mysql. This is not done centrally through mysql. This is why I changed the tagging of your question.